# Animation Game in Jquery

Tags: jquery

### I have a game like

1  2  3

---

4  5  6

---

7  8

When clicked on 6 or 8 the numbers 6 and 8 should move to the blankspace below 6 or blank space after 8.The implementation needs to be implemented in li format for each of the numbers.Please suggest.HTML for the above game is below.The HTML Should not be changed.Please clarify.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <style>

    ul {
      list-style-type: none;
    }

    .SlidingPuzzleFigure {
      max-height: 230px;
      max-width: 230px;
      margin: 10px;
      background: black;
      border-radius: 5px;
    }
    .SlidingPuzzleFigure .SlidingPuzzle {
      padding: 9px 9px;
      height: 230px;
      width: 230px;
    }
    .SlidingPuzzleFigure .SlidingPuzzle .Tile {
      float: left;
      border-top: 6px solid #CCCCCC;
      border-left: 6px solid #CCCCCC;
      border-right: 6px solid #787878;
      border-bottom: 6px solid #787878;
      background: #fff;
      width: 58px;
      height: 49px;
      font-size: 30px;
      text-align: center;
      padding-top: 9px;
    }
    .SlidingPuzzleFigure figcaption {
      font-size: 20px;
      font-style: italic;
      position: absolute;
      text-indent: 20px;
    }





</style>
</head>

<body>

  <html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=yes">

        <title>Sliding Puzzle Quiz</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <figure class="SlidingPuzzleFigure">

            <ul class="SlidingPuzzle">
              <li class="Tile Tile1">1</li>
              <li class="Tile Tile2">2</li>
              <li class="Tile Tile3">3</li>
              <li class="Tile Tile4">4</li>
              <li class="Tile Tile5">5</li>
              <li class="Tile Tile6">6</li>
              <li class="Tile Tile7">7</li>
              <li class="Tile Tile8">8</li>
            </ul>

        <figcaption>A Sliding Puzzle</figcaption>
    </figure>
    </body>
</html>



</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/me9pet2y/1/:

```js
$(function() {
 $('#game td').click(function(){
    var id=$(this).attr('id');
    //alert(id)
       if(id=='td1')
       {
            if(isEmpty('td2')) swap(id,'td2');
            else if(isEmpty('td4')) swap(id,'td4');
       }
       if(id=='td2')
       {
            if(isEmpty('td1')) swap(id,'td1');
            else if(isEmpty('td3')) swap(id,'td3');
            else if(isEmpty('td5')) swap(id,'td5');
       }
       if(id=='td3')
       {
            if(isEmpty('td2')) swap(id,'td2');
            else if(isEmpty('td6')) swap(id,'td6');
       }
       if(id=='td4')
       {
            if(isEmpty('td1')) swap(id,'td1');
            else if(isEmpty('td5')) swap(id,'td5');
            else if(isEmpty('td7')) swap(id,'td7');
       }
       if(id=='td5')
       {
            if(isEmpty('td2')) swap(id,'td2');
            else if(isEmpty('td4')) swap(id,'td4');
            else if(isEmpty('td6')) swap(id,'td6');
            else if(isEmpty('td8')) swap(id,'td8');
       }
       if(id=='td6')
       {
            if(isEmpty('td9')) swap(id,'td9');
            else if(isEmpty('td5')) swap(id,'td5');
            else if(isEmpty('td3')) swap(id,'td3');
       }
       if(id=='td7')
       {
            if(isEmpty('td4')) swap(id,'td4');
            else if(isEmpty('td8')) swap(id,'td8');
       }       
       if(id=='td8')
       {
            if(isEmpty('td7')) swap(id,'td7');
            else if(isEmpty('td5')) swap(id,'td5');
            else if(isEmpty('td9')) swap(id,'td9');
       }
       if(id=='td9')
       {
            if(isEmpty('td6')) swap(id,'td6');
            else if(isEmpty('td8')) swap(id,'td8');
       }
       
 })
    
    function isEmpty(id)
    {
        var empty=false;
        
        var num=$('#'+id).attr('data-num')
        if(num==0) empty=true;
        
        return empty
    }
    
    function swap(id1,id2)
    {
        var $td1=$('#'+id1);
        var $td2=$('#'+id2);
        
        var num1=$('#'+id1).attr('data-num')
        var num2=$('#'+id2).attr('data-num')
        
        var html1=$td1.html();
        var html2=$td2.html();
        
        $td1.html(html2).attr('data-num',num2);
        $td2.html(html1).attr('data-num',num1);
    }
})
```

```css
#game td{cursor: pointer;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="game">
    <tr>    
        <td id="td1" data-num="1">1</td>
        <td id="td2" data-num="2">2</td>
        <td id="td3" data-num="3">3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>    
        <td id="td4" data-num="4">4</td>
        <td id="td5" data-num="5">5</td>
        <td id="td6" data-num="6">6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>    
        <td id="td7" data-num="7">7</td>
        <td id="td8" data-num="8">8</td>
        <td id="td9" data-num="0"></td>
    </tr>
    
</table>
```